# Is it possible to export the raw text password in Linux when the user is logging in?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-capabilities, linuxthreads

I was just wondering, is it possible to export the raw text password into a file using `echo "$password" >> /home/user/Desktop/file name`. I know that the password is validated against the `shadow file` by `pam_unix.so`. Can the username and password exported before the raw text is being converted?

Comment: If You are able to hook into the process directly after pressing enter in console-logon, then You might have a chance. As You are making LFS, You are relatively free to add/remove/change much stuff, which gives You a handful of options. I think, tty-login or something like this must be spotted to hook into it, I only could say, how to read crypted pw from shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can substitute the **login(1)** command with one of your own and do the thing.  You are in an opensource system.  You are free to reprogram it. I have done it for fun. You can do also.